# How can I get a callback when an arbitrary UIView redraws itself?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, core-animation

I would like to write a class that applies an effect to a `UIView`, similar to `UIVisualEffectView`. I would also like this view to update live -- if the "target" view redraws itself, my view should as well. Obviously I  can just redraw on every frame using a `CADisplayLink` or `NSTimer`, but I would prefer not to waste the user's battery unnecessarily.

I see that `CALayer`/`UIView` objects have a `needsDisplay` boolean object, but this seems to be something that the client sets, rather than the system exposing it, so it doesn't seem to be any help.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Use notification center and add that view as observer..which has to be updated when another view redraws itself. and you should post notification when that view redraws itself.

Comment: @user3680929 sure, but how do I know that that view has to redraw itself so I can post the notification in the first place?

Comment: setNeedsLayout and layoutSubviews..let me work on the code for this.

Comment: I want to be able to do this for *any* view, not just ones that descend from a view that I've subclassed to send a notification or call out to a delegate.

Comment: "I want to be able to do this for any view, not just ones that descend from a view that I've subclassed" The only way to do that would be to reach into UIView _itself_ and modify it. That is a very, very bad idea. But it can be done: http://nshipster.com/swift-objc-runtime/

Comment: @matt I'm aware of this solution, and I agree; it is a bad idea to do this. I was hoping I might have overlooked some API or esoteric KVO thing that would let me do this. Thanks for suggesting it, though.